# html5 video tag is not started sometimes on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a tag

```
<video controls="true" autoplay="true" type="video/mp4">
```

I set src tag manually like this:

```
$('video').attr('src',b64str)
```

and it works in firefox. But sometimes it doesn't work in Chrome. I didn't manage to understand why sometimes it fails or not on Chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope your browser is an updated version. Why don't you use  type="video/webm" also.